# How do I focus a foreign window?

Tags: c#, .net, focus

I have an application which may only have one instance of itself open at a time. To enforce this, I use this code:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process[] myProcesses = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses();
System.Diagnostics.Process me = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess();
foreach (System.Diagnostics.Process p in myProcesses)
{
    if (p.ProcessName == me.ProcessName)
        if (p.Id != me.Id)
        {
            //if already running, abort this copy.
            return;
        }
}
//launch the application.
//...
```

It works fine. I would also like it to be able to focus the form of the already-running copy.  That is, before returning, I want to bring the other instance of this application into the foreground.

How do I do that?

SetForegroundWindow works, to a point:

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd); 

// ...
if (p.Id != me.Id)
{
    //if already running, focus it, and then abort this copy.
    SetForegroundWindow(p.MainWindowHandle);
    return;
}
// ...
```

This does bring the window to the foreground if it is not minimized.  Awesome.
If the window IS minimized, however, it remains minimized.

It needs to un-minimize.

Solution via SwitchToThisWindow (Works!):

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern void SwitchToThisWindow(IntPtr hWnd, bool fAltTab);

[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
    System.Diagnostics.Process me = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess();
    System.Diagnostics.Process[] myProcesses = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName(me.ProcessName);
    foreach (System.Diagnostics.Process p in myProcesses)
    {
        if (p.Id != me.Id)
        {
            SwitchToThisWindow(p.MainWindowHandle, true);
            return;
        }
    }
    //now go ahead and start our application ;-)
}
```

Comment: Check to see if the window IsIconic, if so call ShowWindow 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633527(VS.85).aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633548(VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had the same problem and [SwitchToThisWindow()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633553.aspx) worked the best for me. The only limitation is that you must have XP sp1 installed. I played with SetForegroundWindow, ShowWindow, and they both had problems pulling the window into view.

Comment: Take note, though, that the linked MSDN page says "[This function is not intended for general use. It may be altered or unavailable in subsequent versions of Windows.]"

Answer (score 8):

C# equivalent of Tom Juergens's answer. Works like a charm for me.

```
private const  int SW_SHOWNORMAL = 1;

[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
private static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hwnd, int nCmdShow);

[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hwnd);

public void SetForeground()
{
    Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("process name");

    foreach (Process p in processes) {
        ShowWindow(p.MainWindowHandle, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
        SetForegroundWindow(p.MainWindowHandle);
    }
}
```

Comment: how can we simplify the above to just quick launch the application that is already running?

Answer (score 5):

Same as OP, I found that `SetForegroundWindow` alone wasn't enough when the window was minimized. Since I didn't want to use `SwitchToThisWindow`, I chose `ShowWindow` followed by `SetForegroundWindow`.

Works well for me!

```
private const SW_SHOWNORMAL = 1

<DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)> _
Private Function ShowWindow(ByVal hwnd As IntPtr, ByVal nCmdShow As integer) As Boolean
End Function

<DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True)> _
Private Function SetForegroundWindow(ByVal hwnd As IntPtr) As Boolean
End Function

Sub SetForeground()
    Dim processes As Process() = Process.GetProcessesByName("myprocess")

    For Each p as Process in processes
        ShowWindow(p.MainWindowHandle, SW_SHOWNORMAL)
        SetForegroundWindow(p.MainWindowHandle)
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe you will want to use [SetForegroundWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633539(VS.85).aspx)

[MSDN Example](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/42b3db75-e61e-4f59-bf2b-c96a40cfb4e4/)

Answer (score 2):

Complete Side Note...

You can use

```
Process.GetProcessesByName(me.ProcessName)
```

instead of looping over all the processes running on the system...

**UPDATE**

[PInvoke](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/ShowWindow.html) Rules for this sort of thing...

Answer (score 0):

Can you grab MainWindowHandle property of the Process object and send it a WM_USER message that you can interpret as "some other instance wants to bring me to the front".

Comment: Could do that, seems ugly though.  It might be a good alternative if SetForegroundWindow doesn't pan out.

Answer (score 0):

It is a very frequent behavior in desktop applications, I regularly have to do this when I create a new WPF application. So I have created a SingletonApp class which inherits from Application :

```
public class SingletonApp : Application
{
    private static readonly System.Threading.Mutex mutex;
    private static readonly string processName;

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int flags);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hwnd);

    static SingletonApp()
    {
        processName = Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName;
        mutex = new System.Threading.Mutex(false, $"Local\\{processName}");
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// A base class for application needing to prevent multiple instances
    /// </summary>
    public SingletonApp()
    {
        if (!mutex.WaitOne(0, false))
        {
            // Give focus to existing instance before shutdown
            BringToFront(processName);

            Current.Shutdown();
        }
    }

    public void BringToFront(string processName)
    {
        Process process = Process.GetProcessesByName(processName).FirstOrDefault();

        if (process != null)
        {
            // In case of window is minimized
            ShowWindow(process.MainWindowHandle, 1);     // 1 = Normal

            SetForegroundWindow(process.MainWindowHandle);
        }
    }
}
```

To use it, you just have to inherit from SingletonApp instead of Application in your App.xaml.cs :

```
public partial class App : SingletonApp
```

Don't forget to update App.xaml too :

```
<utils:SingletonApp x:Class="MyApp.App"
             [...]
             xmlns:utils="clr-namespace:MyApp.Utils"
             Startup="App_OnStartup">
```

With this it becomes very easy to implement this behavior in every new desktop client.