# Correct way (in .NET) to switch the focus to another application

Tags: .net, process, pinvoke

This is what I have so far:

```
Dim bProcess = Process.GetProcessesByName("By").FirstOrDefault
If bProcess IsNot Nothing Then
    SwitchToThisWindow(bProcess.MainWindowHandle, True)
Else
    Process.Start("C:\Program Files\B\B.exe")
End If
```

It has two problems.

1. Some people have told me that SwitchToThisWindow is deprecated.
2. If application B is minimized, this function silently fails from the user's perspective.

So what's the right way to do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I focus a foreign window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/444430/how-do-i-focus-a-foreign-window)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Get the window handle (hwnd), and then use this user32.dll function:

VB.net declaration:

```
Declare Function SetForegroundWindow Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hwnd As Integer) As Integer
```

C# declaration:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")] public static extern int SetForegroundWindow(int hwnd)
```

One consideration is that this will not work if the window is minimized, so I've written the following method which also handles this case. Here is the C# code, it should be fairly straight forward to migrate this to VB.

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
[return: System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAs(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.Bool)]
private static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, ShowWindowEnum flags);

[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern int SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hwnd);

private enum ShowWindowEnum
{
    Hide = 0,
    ShowNormal = 1, ShowMinimized = 2, ShowMaximized = 3,
    Maximize = 3, ShowNormalNoActivate = 4, Show = 5,
    Minimize = 6, ShowMinNoActivate = 7, ShowNoActivate = 8,
    Restore = 9, ShowDefault = 10, ForceMinimized = 11
};

public void BringMainWindowToFront(string processName)
{
    // get the process
    Process bProcess = Process.GetProcessesByName(processName).FirstOrDefault();

    // check if the process is running
    if (bProcess != null)
    {
        // check if the window is hidden / minimized
        if (bProcess.MainWindowHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            // the window is hidden so try to restore it before setting focus.
            ShowWindow(bProcess.Handle, ShowWindowEnum.Restore);
        }

        // set user the focus to the window
        SetForegroundWindow(bProcess.MainWindowHandle);
    }
    else
    {
        // the process is not running, so start it
        Process.Start(processName);
    }
}
```

Using that code, it would be as simple as setting the appropriate process variables and calling `BringMainWindowToFront("processName");`

Comment: Why are declaring it as Integer instead of IntPtr?

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. Can you show me how to use it in conjunction with the code in the original question?

Comment: I'm getting a zero for SetActiveWindow's return value, which indicates an error. But I'm also getting 0 for GetLastWin32Error, which indicates success. Any idea where to look next?

Comment: For ShowWindow, I need to pass bProcess.MainWindowHandle. What's really frustrating is that your code works on every application except the one I need it for.

Comment: Int32 as handle will not work correctly on 64-bit. It just *seems* to work, since you're on a 32-bit machine or OS. IntPtr is defined to be of the same size as the bit-ness of the operating system, so running on a 64-bit OS will give you 64-bit IntPtr's.

Comment: Note that `SetActiveWindow()` simply activates a foreground window.   If you want to switch focus, use `SetForegroundWindow()`

Comment: This only works for me in windows 10. But it does not work on windows 2008 server R2 Standar. Any idea why?

Comment: According to the docs, the bProcess.MainWindowHandle will only be 0 if  there's zero UI; if it's just minimized this will not trap that case. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.mainwindowhandle(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: It does not look like it's working when an app has two or more windows.

Answer (score 45):

There is another way, which uses the not well-known UI Automation API:

```
AutomationElement element = AutomationElement.FromHandle(process.MainWindowHandle);
if (element != null)
{
    element.SetFocus();
}
```

Most of the time, this will work if it's possible to switch to that window. There are a lot of limitations in Windows (security, UAC, specific configuration, etc...) that can prevent you to change the end-user focus.

Comment: +1 For highlighting a little-known technique. Very nice and thanks for expanding my knowledge.

Comment: .NET 4.5: AutomationElement is in  UIAutomationClient (in UIAutomationClient.dll)

Comment: Worth noting that this won't work if the window has been hidden and doesn't have a task bar icon. (MainWindowHandle will be null)

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up, @teynon but just for diligence, AutomationElement seems to exist from .NET 3.0 onwards: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.automation.automationelement(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks! Really helped med out :) Works much better than SetForegroundWindow for my use

Answer (score 8):

Create a New Class in your project and copy-paste the below code in it.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Threading;

namespace MyProject
{
    public class ProcessHelper
    {
        public static void SetFocusToExternalApp(string strProcessName)
        {
            Process[] arrProcesses = Process.GetProcessesByName(strProcessName);
            if (arrProcesses.Length > 0)
            {

                IntPtr ipHwnd = arrProcesses[0].MainWindowHandle;
                Thread.Sleep(100);
                SetForegroundWindow(ipHwnd);

            }
        }

    //API-declaration
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

    }
}
```

Now copy-paste the below code in your required area.

```
string procName = Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName;
ProcessHelper.SetFocusToExternalApp(procName);
```

Here you are calling the function to bring focus to the other application's window.

Answer (score 5):

In VB.Net, you can use the [AppActivate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9784w8e%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) function.

```
Dim App As Process() = Process.GetProcessesByName("program.exe")
If App.Length > 0 Then
   AppActivate(App(0).Id)
End If
```

Answer (score 4):

I used SetForegroundWindow to make the window from another application appear.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);
```

[How can I give another Process focus from C#?](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/42b3db75-e61e-4f59-bf2b-c96a40cfb4e4)

Answer (score 3):

This work for me

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern void SwitchToThisWindow(IntPtr hWnd, bool turnOn);
[STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Process bProcess = Process.GetProcessesByName(processnamehere).FirstOrDefault() ;
            if (bProcess != null)
                    {
                        SwitchToThisWindow(bProcess.MainWindowHandle, true);
                    }
                GC.Collect();
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Imports:

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
```

Put this in a Module

```
<DllImport("user32.dll")> _
Private Function SetForegroundWindow(hWnd As IntPtr) As Boolean
End Function

Public Sub FocusWindow(ByVal ProcessName As String)
    Dim p As System.Diagnostics.Process = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName(ProcessName).FirstOrDefault
    If p IsNot Nothing Then
        SetForegroundWindow(p.MainWindowHandle)
        SendKeys.SendWait("~") ' maximize the application if it's minimized
    End If
End Sub
```

Usage:

```
FocusWindow("Notepad")
```

Source: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/232649/Setting-Focus-on-an-External-application#_rating

Answer (score 1):

Following worked for me, when I tried for applications like SQL Server Management Studio and Visual Studio, running as **Administrator**, using the `exe` got from the following code.

Toggle Helper

```
public class ToggleHelper
{
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
    [return: System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAs(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, EnumForWindow enumVal);

    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern int SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hwnd);

    private enum EnumForWindow
    {
        Hide = 0,
        ShowNormal = 1, ShowMinimized = 2, ShowMaximized = 3,
        Maximize = 3, ShowNormalNoActivate = 4, Show = 5,
        Minimize = 6, ShowMinNoActivate = 7, ShowNoActivate = 8,
        Restore = 9, ShowDefault = 10, ForceMinimized = 11
    };

    public void SetForeGroundMainWindowHandle(string processName)
    {

        Console.WriteLine("SetForeGroundMainWindowHandle Called - for "+ processName);
        Process p = Process.GetProcessesByName(processName).FirstOrDefault();

        if (p != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(p.MainWindowHandle.ToString());
            ShowWindow(p.MainWindowHandle, EnumForWindow.Restore);
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
            ShowWindow(p.MainWindowHandle, EnumForWindow.ShowMaximized);
            //System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
            SetForegroundWindow(p.MainWindowHandle);
        }
        else
        {
            Process.Start(processName);
        }
    }
}
```

Client

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //RUN AS Administrator
        var y = Process.GetProcesses().Where(pr => pr.MainWindowHandle != IntPtr.Zero);
        foreach (Process proc in y)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(proc.ProcessName);
        }

        ToggleHelper t = new ToggleHelper();

        int a = 0;
        while (a <= 1)
        {
            t.SetForeGroundMainWindowHandle("Ssms");
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(30000);
            t.SetForeGroundMainWindowHandle("devenv");
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(18000);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```