# How to set focus to a process?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a System.Diagnostics.Process variable named _program.
I understand that not every process have a user interface, so it will never have a focus (I think).
But, supposing that this process has a interface, is it possible to set focus to it ? Maybe I need to use Process.StandardInput?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Correct way (in .NET) to switch the focus to another application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2315561/correct-way-in-net-to-switch-the-focus-to-another-application)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use PInvoke to call a native function to set the foreground window:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

[DllImport("User32.dll")]
private static extern Int32 SetForegroundWindow(nint hWnd);

void YourMethod()
{
  Process p = ... // However you create your process
  SetForegroundWindow(p.MainWindowHandle);  // Set this process's main window as the foreground window
}
```