# C# File Association: passing double clicked file path to string

Tags: c#

I recently made a notepad like program for C# and found a library for using file associations. I am wondering how I would pass the path of the file double clicked in explorer, to a string so the file can read and 'open' the text file (like how notepad does). I have googled for a while, and asked around a few forums, and my friends. Any answers or nudges in the right direction are appreciated. Thank You

(note: I've already tried reading it from the `string[] args` paramater in `Main()`, which was suggested by someone else)

EDIT: Solved, it was the `args[0]`. I was really tired when I started on this

Comment: are you asking how to associate a file extension with your program?

Comment: Check out my similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7798259/how-to-execute-an-event-of-already-launched-application-with-file-association

Comment: When trying o read from `args`, what didn't work?

Comment: or are you asking `When a file has been opened using my program, how do I access that file`?

Comment: @Oded when I did string filePath = args[0]; and it returned an index out of bounds exception

Comment: How have you associated the file type with your application?

Comment: Can you show us how you handle the args in your application?

Comment: protip:  since people took the time to write you an answer, you might want to see if at least one of the provided answers is indeed correct and mark it as such.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works fine for me!

```
public static void Main(string[] args){            
     if (args.Length == 0){
       // Show your application usage or show an error box              
       return;
     }
     string file = args[0];
     Application.Run(new MyProgram(file));           
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The suggestion was correct, the filename you double-click on in explorer will be visible in your app as an args parameter. Then you can do what you like with it, such as open a file.

Answer (score 1):

I've just made the following program

When opening a file with this program, it tells me the path of the file.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Console.WriteLine(args.Length);
        foreach (string s in args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(s);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();

    }
}
```

the output for me was

```
1
C:\Users\MyUserName\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\bin\Debug\New Text Document.txt
```

you might want to execute a similar program, by using file.openWith, to see what happens.